# How to make this sed 'grab text between 2 keywords' case-insensitive?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, match

**test.txt**

```
Welcome notice
------------------------
Hello there, welcome! Foo

hello

world

Bar
Yes!
Foo

How are ya?!

Bar

Have a great day!
```

**sed - grab text**

```
$ sed -n '/Foo/,/Bar/p' test.txt
```

**Output**

```
Hello there, welcome! Foo

hello

world

Bar
Foo

How are ya?!

Bar
```

How to make this case-insensitive? For instance, say 'FOO' or 'bAr' will match the match pattern for sed? I tried with 'I', no luck. This should be a quick one, thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your sed supports it you can use I ...

```
sed -n '/Foo/I,/Bar/Ip' text.txt
```

If not you will have to do something like

```
sed -n '/[fF][oO][oO]/,/[bB][aA][rR]/p' text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed -n '/Foo/,/Bar/Ip' test.txt`